# Rails5: Open excel file in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, file, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using shrine for excel file uploading. File is successfully uploaded and linked to model instances using shrine.

I wanted to open that Excel file(.xls, .xlsx) in browser instead of downloading it. I have looked for various solutions and tried them, but no luck.

The recommended solution from most of the people is using 'send_data', I have tried with that also:

```
send_file(data, type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: "#{uploaded_file.metadata["filename"]}", disposition: 'inline')
```

But it is downloading the file instead of opening it directly in browser.

My questions are

1) Is this opening/downloading file depends on browser settings?

2) Which one is better? To open a file in browser OR use gem like 'axlsx' to create and render excel templates in app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whether the browser will attempt to open the file in the browser or download it is determined by the `Content-Disposition` response header.

```
Content-Disposition: inline     # browser will attempt to display it
Content-Disposition: attachment # browser will always download it
```

You can also specify the filename in both cases, should the user choose to download it:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="table.xls"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="table.xls"
```

How to ensure that the `Content-Disposition` is specified to `inline` depends on where you're storing your files. If you're storing them on the filesystem, I think that the `Rails::Static` middleware already has the "inline" behaviour. If not, you can switch to [download_endpoint](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Plugins/DownloadEndpoint.html).

If you're storing them on Amazon S3, you can specify the default `:content_disposition` upload option on `Shrine::Storage::S3` initialization:

```
Shrine::Storage::S3.new(upload_options: {content_disposition: "inline"}, **options)
```